# Angular build Failing with "Data path '.sourceMap' should be object."

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I am building my angular application using the angular CLI command
`ng test --source-map=false`

Everything was working fine, but suddenly I have started encountering the below error

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path ".sourceMap" should be object.
Data path ".sourceMap" should be boolean.
Data path ".sourceMap" should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

On some inspection, the issue seems to originate from the `--source-map` parameter, but not sure about the exact cause.

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems it has something to do with the dev-dep `@angular-devkit/build-angular`. After downgrading this package everything works fine again.

Comment: The problem for me was due an incompatible version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` with angular **6**. Btw. I've downgraded `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to `~0.8.9` which seems to be the last compatible version.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug with the --source-map flag that would throw those errors. The latest version of the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` has a fix for this (0.13.6).

Comment: I have `@angular-devkit/build-angular` 0.13.8 and have the same issue.

Comment: angular broke semver it looks like latest version is now 0.8.9 https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular (versions tab)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for source maps is

```
--sourceMap=true|false
```

See : https://angular.io/cli/test

Comment: This if for Angular 7. For Angular 6 the parameter is as @goyalM has specified.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version,the cmd params is like this " ng build --prod --source-map ".

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that i used ngx-build-plus which is not yet based on the Angular CLI 7.2 style config for "sourceMap". The temporary workaround that I used is described here https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/88#issuecomment-490433864

Answer (score 0):

Is your command correct.I think it should be ng test --sourcemaps=false